# Binary Sector overlay diagram in a radial plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I am analyzing some data from a system that can have some binary configurations. I thought that a good strategy would be to visualize the output as a radial plot and overlay its binary configuration like sectors, as can be seen in the image.

[image]

My problem is the following I'm trying to automatize the part of plotting the colored sectors. Is there any package TikZ package that would simplify my life? Is there any package that allowing to transform a number (in this case 1..7) into binary and then examine the binary string to color the sectors accordingly ?

I thought that in the examples website I would find some binary encoding to generate patterns such as the ones used to generate optic encoders like those in the figure, but I did not. There's though a dardboard, but the problem is different the coloring is done manually. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using `\pgfmathparse` , `\foreach` and bitset [`bitset` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bitset)

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bitset}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{
    % argumentss = {initialAngle, radiousOffset, sectorAngleSize, thickness}
    sect/.style args={#1:#2:#3:#4}{
    insert path={   +(#1:#2) arc (#1:{#1+#3}:#2)  
                 -- +({#1+#3}:#4) arc ({#1+#3}:#1:{#2+#4}) 
                 -- cycle     }
  }
}
\tikzset{activeSector/.style={very thin, fill=black!20}}
\tikzset{inactiveSector/.style={very thin}}


\def\numBits{3}
\def\initialRadious{2}
\def\sectorThickness{.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\numSectors}{(2^\numBits)-1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\maxIdxNumBits}{\numBits-1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\sectorSize}{360/\numSectors}


\foreach \x [count=\n] in {1,...,\numSectors}
{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\currentAngle}{\sectorSize*\x}
    \bitsetSetDec{xInbin}{\x}
    \foreach \bitId in {0,...,\maxIdxNumBits}
    {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\currentRadious}{\initialRadious+\sectorThickness*(\bitId-1)}
        \pgfmathparse{\bitsetGet{xInbin}{\bitId})}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult>0      
                    \draw[activeSector] (0,0) [sect=\currentAngle:
                                                    \currentRadious:
                                                    \sectorSize:
                                                    \sectorThickness];
        \else
                    \draw[inactiveSector] (0,0) [sect=\currentAngle:
                                                    \currentRadious:
                                                    \sectorSize:
                                                    \sectorThickness];
        \fi
    }
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

**Edit:** I slightly (or greatly) misunderstood the OP's requirements. The original answer is at the bottom.

This answer requires the *latest CVS version of PGF* for the new `math` library. Note that as this hasn't formed part of an official release it may (but is unlikely to) change.

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzmath{
    int \nbits, \p, \q, \N, \n;
    \nbits = 3;
    \p = 2^\nbits;
    \s = (360/\p);
    \r = 1;
    \t = 0.5;
    for \N in {0,...,\p-1}{ 
        \n = \N;
        {
            \node [font=\tiny, anchor=\N*\s+\s/2] at (\N*\s+\s/2:\r) {\N};
        };
        for \i in {0, ..., \nbits-1}{
            \q = 2^(\nbits-\i-1);
            if int(\n/\q) > 0 then {
                let \c = black;
                \n = \n - \q;
            } else {
                let \c = white;
            };
            \R = \r + \t*(\nbits- \i - 1);
            \a = \N*\s;
            \b = \a + \s;
            {
                \path [fill=\c, draw=black!75, very thick] 
                    (\a:\R) arc (\a:\b:\R) -- (\b:\R+\t) arc (\b:\a:\R+\t) -- cycle;
            };
        };
    };
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** The rest of this answer is is the initial (wrong) answer.

Everything could have been done using `\pgfmathparse` and `\foreach`, but the `math` library aims to make multiple assignments a bit more clean. Also this answer does not cover adding the radial plot on top. More generic solutions (e.g., using `pgfplots`) are hopefully possible.

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzmath{
    int \nbits, \n, \q;
    \nbits = 8;
    \s = (360/\nbits);
    \r1 = 1;
    \r2 = 1.5;
    \k = 0;
    for \n in {0,1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,15,33,65,163,211,244,255}{
        \x = mod(\k, 4);
        \y = int(\k/4);
        \k = \k + 1;
        {
            \node at (\x*4,-\y*4) {\n};
        };
        for \i in {0, ..., \nbits-1}{
            \q = 2^(\nbits-\i-1);
            if int(\n/\q) > 0 then {
                let \c1 = black;
                let \c2 = white;
                \n = \n - \q;
            } else {
                let \c1 = white;
                let \c2 = black;
            };
            \a = \s * \i;
            \b = \a + \s;
            {
                \begin{scope}[shift={(\x*4,-\y*4)}]
                    \path [fill=\c1, draw=black!75, very thick] 
                        (\a:\r1) arc (\a:\b:\r1) -- (\b:\r2) arc (\b:\a:\r2) -- cycle;
                    \node [font=\tiny, text=\c2] at (\a+\s/2:\r1/2+\r2/2) {\q};
                \end{scope}
            };
        };
    };
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With some minor adjustments it is possible to get "dartboard" patterns:

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzmath{
    int \nbits, \n, \q;
    \nbits = 8;
    \s = (360/\nbits);
    \r1 = 2;
    \r2 = 2.5;
    for \n in {65,163,211,244,255}{ \k = 0;
        for \i in {0, ..., \nbits-1}{
            \q = 2^(\nbits-\i-1);
            if int(\n/\q) > 0 then {
                let \c1 = black;
                \n = \n - \q;
            } else {
                let \c1 = white;
            };
            \a = \s * \i;
            \b = \a + \s;
            {               
                    \path [fill=\c1, draw=black!75, very thick] 
                        (\a:\r1) arc (\a:\b:\r1) -- (\b:\r2) arc (\b:\a:\r2) -- cycle;
            };
        };
        \r1 = \r2;
        \r2 = \r2 + 0.5;
    };
    for \i in {0, ..., \nbits-1}{
        \a = (360/\nbits) * (\i);
        \q = 2^(\nbits-\i-1);
        {
            \node [font=\tiny] at (\a+\s/2:1.625) {\q};
        };
    };
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote, can be used.

The number of rings is determined by `\n`. The number of slices in each ring is `2^\n` and this is passed to the key `total count`.

The color (`black` or `white`) of the slices is determined in the key `slices style`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\n{4}
\foreach\i in {1,...,\n}{
  \wheelchart[
    radius={\i+1}{\i+2},
    slices style={
      /utils/exec={
        \pgfmathparse{Mod(int((\WCcount-1)/(2^(\i-1))),2)==0?"black":"white"}
        \edef\WCcolor{\pgfmathresult}
      },
      \WCcolor,
      draw=gray,
      ultra thick
    },
    start angle=0,
    total count=2^\n
  ]{}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```