# What are the packages require to draw this stamp below?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, logos

[image: Stamp image]

I capture this image so you could see any possibilities to help me out I know how to write Latex but having no background to draw.

Comment: `tikz` is a package which definitely can draw something like that. But there are other packages as well.

Comment: `tikz`, `pstricks`... etc.

Comment: I'd love to see an approach with tikz on this one ...

Comment: The answers to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134062/binary-sector-overlay-diagram-in-a-radial-plot) may provide a useful starting point.

Comment: @samcarter: Thanks, I know that group. I thought recently to participate there with my Physics courses

Comment: This [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/271247/12571) can be relevant.

Comment: Is the image supposed to represent a rotary encoder?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Adapting a bit one [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/271247/12571) of mine from [another similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271240/color-specific-sections-of-three-concentric-circles), I wrote the following code:

(**Updated** to include the punched rectangle)

(**Update2** to add the text in the center):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}
\def\sector#1#2#3#4#5{%
\fill[#5] (#1) -- (#3:#2) arc (#3:#4:#2) -- cycle;
}


% Define colors for bits 1 and 0
\colorlet{color1}{blue!30!black}
\colorlet{color0}{white}

\def\mylogo{\color{color1}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\emph{Teacher's}        \\
\uppercase{\Huge\LaTeX} \\
\emph{Enthusiasts}
\end{tabular}
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \code [count=\i from=1] in {0110,0100,1100,1000,0000,0001,1001,1101,0101,0111,1111,1011,0011,0010,1010,1110,0110} {
      % \node at (\i*22.5:7.5) {\code}; % Label each code
      % Draw sectors from outside to inside
      \foreach \r in  {7,6,5,4} {
         \StrRight{\code}{1}[\bit]         % Get the rightmost bit
         \StrGobbleRight{\code}{1}[\code]  % Get the remaining left bits
         \xdef\code{\code}  % Set them for the next iteration
         \sector{0,0}{\r}{22.5*\i}{22.5*\i-22.5}{color\bit, draw=color1!80}
       }
    }
    \draw[fill=white] circle(3);

    \node at (0,0) {\scalebox{2}{\mylogo{}}};

    % Rectangle with holes
    \begin{scope}[rotate=11.25]
    \draw[draw=black, fill=white] (2.5,-0.5) rectangle(7.5,0.5) 
          (3.5,0) circle(0.4)
          (4.5,0) circle(0.4)
          (5.5,0) circle(0.4)
          (6.5,0) circle(0.4);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image: Result]

Comment: I am not a `tikz` user, but your facility with it is always impressive.

Comment: **Beautiful** ! I appreciate and the result is very fast. Thank you so much for all of you who try it or view it.

Comment: Studding the *Rectangle with holes*, we observe that you had used 4 circles for the holes, but I can not see in the code why one hole is blue.

Comment: @Sigur The hole is blue because it is a hole! (and below it the sector is blue). You can change the angle of the `scope`, put the holes at intersections and see them. The trick is that the whole shape "rectangle+circles" is drawn in a single `\draw` command, so it is a single path. Filling that path leaves the holes (because of the rules of filling complex shapes which intersect themselves or have internal paths).

Comment: @JLDiaz, I didn't know about even/odd rule in that case. I observed a single `;` but I supposed that it would produce 1 rectangle and 4 filled circles. Nice!